# Why is "professional and personal lives" more common than "professional and private lives"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

According to Google Ngram Viewer, ["public and **private** lives" is more common than "public and **personal** lives"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=public%20and%20private%20lives%2Cpublic%20and%20personal%20lives&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpublic%20and%20private%20lives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpublic%20and%20personal%20lives%3B%2Cc0). I understand that "private" is a better contrast to "public" than "personal" is because "private" has a meaning of secret.

What I don't understand is why ["professional and **personal** lives" is more common than "professional and **private** lives"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=professional%20and%20personal%20lives%2Cprofessional%20and%20private%20lives&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprofessional%20and%20personal%20lives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprofessional%20and%20private%20lives%3B%2Cc0)? Why does "professional" go better with "personal"?

Comment: I suspect people simply like the matched word "-al"endings.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you agree that private life is a better contrast to public life than personal life because "private" implies secrecy? Or am I thinking too much?

Comment: [Private life](https://www.lexico.com/definition/private_life) doesn't normally imply secrecy.

Comment: Meh, there's maybe a subtle difference. If I go to a rock concert and dance on the stage, that's my personal life, but I wouldn't immediately describe it as my private life.